# How to do write a Python script that inputs all files from a certain subdirectory from command line?

Tags: python, input, command-line

I have multiple text files in a certain subdirectory. All the text files are the same size, same amount of content, etc.

I do not know how to write a python script that takes an input file and can run from the Terminal. For text files 'file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt','file4.txt' in `\subdirectory`, there should be a way to run the script with

```
python script.py --inputfile file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt
```

or something like

```
python script.py (something) \subdirectory
```

should input all text files into the python script and run. How does one do this?

I usually just go to the local subdirectory and run the file from there, i.e.

```
import os 
path = "/Users/name/desktop"
os.chdir(path)

filename = "file.txt"
f = open(filename, 'r')
output = f.read()
```

And 'output' will be the text file. I'm not sure how to write this so that in runs in the command line.

Comment: you should really look at something like argparse https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html but if you are looking for all files in a directory use either os.listdir or glob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want semantics with some sugar you could use argparse,

but you can also process both files and directories given on the command line

```
import sys
import os
import glob

def handle_file(filename):
    # whatever you want to do with the file named filename e.g.
    print(filename)  

for name in sys.argv[1:]:
    if name.find('.txt') != -1: 
        handle_file(name)
    else:
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(name, '*.txt')): 
            handle_file(filename)
```

Given a subdirectory 'files' with files 'foo1.txt' 'foo2.txt', both

```
python script.py files/foo1.txt files/foo2.txt
```

and

```
python script.py files
```

call the handler for all respective `.txt` files.

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty:

```
import sys

files = sys.argv
for f in files:
    print f #or read the files or whatever
```

If you call this program (say, script.py) like so:

```
python script.py file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

the output will be

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Now, a much nicer way (but with slightly more code) can be achieved with

```
import argparse
```

you can read about that module.

Comment: a note: `sys.argv` separates the command line arguments by whitespace, so make sure to wrap any file name with spaces in them with quotation marks. a second note: you need to iterate over `sys.argv[1:]` or you will process the name of your script as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 'argparse' module, the first example in the docs has a solution for your use case: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 0):

> How to do write a Python script that inputs all files from a certain
>   subdirectory from command line?

1. You can use the wildcard `*` on the command line to get all the files in a directory:

   `$ python prog.py ./path/to/subdir/*.*`
2. In a python program, `sys.argv` is a list of all the arguments passed on the command line:

---

```
import sys

for fname in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(fname) as f:
        print(f.read())
```